# Adding the "source" directory to the PATH variable and then using it

Tags: linux, path, environment-variables

I had to first add the source directory to my PATH variable. So I did this...

```
cd /usr/src
PATH=$PATH:.
```

then I have to run the `phmenu` program in the easiest way, implying I use my new modified PATH variable.

I don't know how to go about doing this. Inside the `src` directory (what I added to PATH) there is a subdirectory called `packages`.

Did I add the wrong "source" file to the PATH, is there another it can be referring to? Or am I on the right track?

Comment: I wonder why you want to add "." to the $PATH... it is NOT recommended. And please tell us **what you are trying to do** (installing this or that package? following some instructions?) (instead of asking *how* to add pwd to the path, which may, or may not be needed, to do what you need to do), and we may provide you an even better option? (We don't want to hunt solutions for an XYProblem ...)

Comment: I definitely used the absolute path once like was suggested and I see why it is not good to add the current directory. I have a question that is asking me to run the "phmenu" program given that I have modified my PATH variable. However, I do not know how to do so. I was wondering if I added the correct directory?

Comment: to have your PATH variable set for a long time: edit one of your shell's startup script ( ~/.profile,   or  ~/.bash_profile , I'd guess). That way if you exit/return, it will still be set. Then you can simply:  `phmenu` (and, using your PATH, it will be found and started)

Answer (score 1):

Use an absolute path like:

```
cd /usr/src
PATH="$PATH:$(pwd)"
```

or simply:

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/src"
```